# Handling end-of-URL slashes in Struts2 actions

Tags: struts2

In my struts.xml I have the following configured in order to handle redirection of `myhost.com/admin` and `myhost.com/admin/` correctly:

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>

<action name="admin">
    <result type="redirectAction">admin/home</result>
</action>
<action name="admin/">
    <result type="redirectAction">admin/home</result>
</action>
```

Is there a quicker way to do this in Struts2?

Comment: What do you mean quicker?

Comment: less verbose, less repetitive typing? I checked the wildcard support in Struts2 and I can actually do something like `name="admin**"` but that would catch everything. That's what I am doing currently, and adding this mapping to the end of the package so it's the last mapping to resolve but I want to know if there is an alternative solution for this.

Comment: Alternative? Rename admin to administrator and remove last mapping in the config.

Comment: You are mixing two things: action and namespace. As an example please try create admin.html and admin.html/, is it possible?

Comment: @RomanC I'm not sure whether to take your comment as helpful or sarcastic, but thanks for your input.

Comment: @LukaszLenart You are correct. I've actually been defaulting all my namespaces to `/` and this has been causing me extra work. If you could place your comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two things: action and namespace. You can use the below config:

```
<action name="admin">
    <result type="redirectAction">admin/</result>
</action>
<action name="" namespace="admin">
    <result>/admin/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

AS commented by yourself, have you tried the wildcard like this

**admin/****

hope this helps